# Assign Lead To a person

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I create a new lead.

[image]

Based on a criteria, I assign to another person.

In this case 5 == 5, so it will always be true.

[image]

How can I confirm the lead has now been assigned  to this person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, I would advise simply writing `TRUE` instead of `5==5`

To answer your question, 
You can confirm that the lead has been assigned to this person by

1. creating the lead (ensure the 'Assign using active assignment is checked')
2. verify that the user listed in the `Lead Owner` field was switched to the user listed in your assignment rule.

[image: Assign using active assignment rule checkbox]

To display this checkbox on the new lead page layout see this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205662&type=1) or [this one](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DNbUAAW)